# Is there a way to data-bind to un known field if angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I know this is a little bit wierd question, but I am stuck. I've tried many leads but none of them was productive. So perhaps I don't know what to look for. What I need is only a direction, no need in a plain solution. This is my problem:

let's say I have a span:

```
<span ng-bind='someField'></span>
```

'someField' is data field that can be changed according to the language selected.
I have an object that contains two fields: 'Text_EN' and 'Text_DE'. I need to conditionaly databind it instead of 'someField'. I need it in runtime, when the user changes the language of the website.
Is that even possible what I want?

Comment: could you just use an `ng-if` and have two spans? Thats a simple and very common solution. Otherwise you could bind to a function instead of a single data member.

Answer (score 0):

How do you determine which object you want? In your controller I'm going to assume your code looks like this:

```
...
$scope.myObject = {
    Text_EN: "English Text",
    Text_DE: "German Text"
};
$scope.currentLanguage = "EN";
...
```

Then in your html you can have this:

```
<span data-ng-bind="myObject['Text_' + currentLanguage]"></span>
```

If this is not how you have it structured please provide more code

Answer (score 0):

You should use a service in charge of i18n (internationalization).

Either implement it yourself or use something as http://angular-translate.github.io/